# Elasticsearch score precision

Tags: java, lucene, elasticsearch

My problem is:

There is an index in my Elasticsearch with a very sensitive field of the type `double` which I use for '_score' calculation. Firstly, when is store this value to an index, Elasticsearch cuts its value, but then I found an additional mapping parameter: `precision_step`, which resolves my problem with correct value storing. But I still have a problem with correct `_score`
sensitivity, because Elasticsearch rounds it's value.

So, my question is:

How I can set some `precision` parameters (like `precision_step`) for result `_score` value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to expand the range of the score. Let's say scores range to 0.0 to 10.0 -- you could multiply each score by a constant 100, thereby reducing the rounding errors (yielding a range of 0.0 to 1000.0). You have to experiment to find the right constant multiplier for your application.